# XMLHttpRequest lack cache on WebWorker

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, browser-cache, web-worker

I have a problem with caching XMLHttpRequest on WebWorker.

I am running an node.js file server which has the task of compressing and storing files before sending them. I send all necessary headers for enabling caching in any request from chrome.

The problem rises when trying to do the same thing from WebWorker.
chrome then sends kind of 2 requests for the same file one with method "OPTIONS" and one with method "GET". (but only the "OPTIONS" one really reaches the server and is sent back data)

First request:

```
Remote Address:[My test server]:3000
Request URL:http://[My test server]:3000/testAssets/busch/mesh.dae
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:referer, x-requested-with, x-worker-hive
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:[My test server]:3000
Origin:http://[My test server]
Referer:http://[My test server]/WebGL/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Worker-Hive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:max-age=604800
Connection:keep-alive
content-encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Wed, 30 Apr 2014 09:01:15 GMT
Expires:Wed, 07 May 2014 09:01:15 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 06 Apr 2014 15:43:47 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Second request:

```
Remote Address:[My test server]:3000
Request URL:http://[My test server]:3000/testAssets/busch/mesh.dae
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

I am using "jquery.hive.pollen.js" for simplicity sake but couldn't find any reasons for the lack of caching. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` request helps the server to actually know, if it can use the cached file or has to request a new version.

Comment: But how can the server identify that the client has a cached version available without having to send the file again?

Comment: Ah thank you. I just send back Cache-Control, Expires and Last-Modified headers back and it seems to work quite well. (don't know if it is the proper way but it works ;) )